# MDX: Combine two queries results using different date periods in the same query

Tags: ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

I need to do a measure comparison using the same dimensions, but with different date periods. Ex:  "In week 2 the measure A was 15% better than week 1 for customer X". ( I have daily granularity )

But I need to do all this in a single SSAS call, in a single MDX. Today I call the two queries separately in a C# program, and in the C# I combine the results and give the percentual difference.

Below a example of what I do today:

"CustomerX want to know the percentual difference of MyMeasureA in a comparison between week2 and week1 ( DateDim with daily granularity )

So, first I do the query of the first week separately using the C# program:

```
select
measures.MyMeasureA on 0
from MyCube
where
( CustomerDim.CustomerX,
  { DateDim.Date.[1] : DateDim.Date[7] } )
```

I save the result above in my C# program. After that I do the second query using the C#:

```
select
measures.MyMeasureA on 0
from MyCube
where
( CustomerDim.CustomerX,
  { DateDim.Date.[8] : DateDim.Date[14] } )
```

And I save the result in my C# program.
After that, in the C# I combine the 2 results and do the percentual difference and tell to the customer: "In week2 your MeasureA was 4% better than the week1"

So what I need is do the 2 queries and the percentual in one SSAS call. Do the queries and the percentual difference in a single call. The percentual is not a problem, but do the two queries in a single mdx is the problem for me.

Best Regards

Luis

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 tuples as measures in a WITH clause:

```
WITH
MEMBER measures.MyMeasureX AS
(
  measures.MyMeasureA,
  CustomerDim.CustomerX,
  { DateDim.Date.[1] : DateDim.Date[7] } 
)
MEMBER measures.MyMeasureY AS
(
  measures.MyMeasureA,
  CustomerDim.CustomerX,
  { DateDim.Date.[8] : DateDim.Date[14] } 
)
SELECT
{
 measures.MyMeasureX,
 measures.MyMeasureY
} ON 0
FROM MyCube;
```